# Wrong date after query in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, timezone

When I retrieve some elements from the DB with `Model::all()` or any other such as `Model::with(['otherModel')]`, I get an object with a different date from what the DB shows.

On my db:

[image: Column 'created_at' on my DB]

It shows the proper time. But when I query them:

[image: A console log of one of those rows]

The red arrow is the result of the `created_at` column, and the green arrow is a date I inserted on the controller when is created with `Carbon`, like this:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'monto' => 'required',
        'tasa' => 'required',
    ]);

    $request['fecha'] = Carbon::now();
    $request['total'] = 0;

    try {
        Cuenta::create($request->all())->save();

        return response()->json(['ok' => 'ok'], 200);
    } catch (QueryException $ex) {
        $res = $ex->getPrevious()->getMessage();

        return response()->json([
            'response' => $res,
        ]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Carbon date is working well. It saves it on my DB with the right timezone and retreives it with the same date. Instead, the timestamp that automatically sets the time is working well on the DB, but after querying it it changes

I have setted my laravel project timezone to match mine, and I also setted the timezone on SQL just in case, but still doesnt seems to work

#### I tried

To query a row from the DB with the laravel `Model::with()` (or `::find`, any of them) function

#### I was excpecting

Same data as the DB

#### I received

A different date in all rows

Comment: whixh database system are you using, and which format has the column and in whuch time zine runs your scprit and database

Comment: I am totally lost, what is the `created_at` column type on your DB? I am assuming it is a `datetime`. What is the result? you are showing a date that matches with a row on your database, I do not see the issue or error. Please, do post code as text, not images

Comment: Im using Mysql and the created_at column is the one that Laravel creates with the method $table->timestamps() on the migrations, which means that the column type is datetime. Theres a 4 hours difference between what I receive vs what I have on my DB

Comment: And as I mentioned, I have both laravel app.config file and mysql timezone configured as GMT -4, reason why my Carbon instance is working as expected

Comment: `LeonardoLopez` did you define any date format inside your model?

Comment: @FaizanAli no. The "created_at" column is autofilled in SQL, so I don't have anything specified on my model. How could I do this?

Comment: @LeonardoLopez `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d h:i:s';` you can define date format in model. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#timestamps

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:
change timezone in `config/app.php`

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

to whatever timezone you want for example:

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Karachi',
```

Comment: Yes, I did this and also did a cache clear in my project. After that change, the Carbon instance is giving me the right timezone, but I still get a different hour when retreiving the "created_at" column

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
// App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi'); // config('app.timezone')
}
```